# Japanese symbols are not shown in raster image in WinRT

Tags: pdf, rasterizing

I have a small trouble with Japanese symbols when I save rasterized PDF document into PNG. I tried to convert PDF file into the PNG with help of  pitron.PDF.Rasterizer in my Windows Store application. Another files with embedded fonts are converted without problems, but this file does not contain embedded fonts and looks horrible.  [image]

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like some fonts are not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that **Аpitron.Core.Winrt.winmd** is placed at the same folder  as **Аpitron.PDF.Rasterizer.dll**. 
Your PDF file requires external fonts and they could not be loaded at runtime without the types declared in metadata.